# Yii2 Getting a Syntax error on ` $this->modelClass::find()->andWhere(['post_id' => \Yii::$app->request->get('postId')])` which is a valid clause

Tags: php, rest, yii2, yii2-basic-app

am getting this error: "syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ']'"
on a valid clause.

```
<?php namespace app\controllers;

use app\models\Comment;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class CommentController extends ActiveController{

    public $modelClass = Comment::class;

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions(); //Auto generated STUD
        $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this,'prepareDataProvider']; // Replace for custom

        return $actions;
    
    }    

    public function prepareDataProvider()
    {
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            "query" => $this->modelClass::find()->andWhere(['post_id' => \Yii::$app->request->get('postId')])
        ]);
    }

}
```

If I exchange the "$this->modelClass" for "Comment" or any Model name it works fine.
Any idea why this could be happening?

For this we're using PHP 5.6.36 just because the main app was implemented with it.

Comment: Try putting it in curly braces: `{$this->modelClass}`

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Already tried but is taken the syntax to the first brace.

Comment: Try parentheses then.

Comment: Same result: ```syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ']'```

In case is needed The Framework version is 2.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a variable and use that.

```
    public function prepareDataProvider()
    {
        $class = $this->modelClass;
        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            "query" => $class::find()->andWhere(['post_id' => \Yii::$app->request->get('postId')])
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the issue. It would be nice to know why the Framework though it was an error but is OK!. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nothing to do with the framework, it's just PHP syntax.